# POWERSHELL : Get-AdUser as NT AUTHORITY AccountExpirationDate properties blank

Tags: powershell, properties, get-aduser

As domain admin

```
get-aduser -Filter { GivenName
-like 'us')} -searchbase "DC=dom,DC=com" -properties * | Select SamAccountName, SurName, GivenName, @{Label='CurrentDate';Expression={get-date} }, AccountExpires, AccountExpirationDate
```

It s OK.

```
SamAccountName        : us
SurName               : us
GivenName             : us
CurrentDate           : 20/02/2024 15:02:19
AccountExpires        : 133537212000000000
AccountExpirationDate : 01/03/2024 00:00:00
```

But as NT AUTHORITY\System user, output is

```
SamAccountName        : us
SurName               : us
GivenName             : us
CurrentDate           : 20/02/2024 15:02:19
AccountExpires        : 
AccountExpirationDate :
```

Expirations are blank. It was working few weeks ago.
To test as SYSTEM, i use this command :

```
PsExec.exe -i -s C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Have you got a clue? Thanks.

Comment: Using the builtin system account will cause all the ADSI/ADWS calls to assume the machine's domain identity - my best guess is that the computer account (or computer accounts in general in your environment) doesn't have access to read the `accountExpires` attribute on user objects.

Comment: Ok. So is there a workaround? is it safe to add access rights to this property?

Comment: You could (use group-based delegation, don't grant the permission to the computer account directly), but you have to ask yourself "is this really necessary?" - why does your machine need to read the account expiration date for user accounts? What is the end game here?

Comment: The machine runs a script via a scheduled task as SYSTEM to send the expiration of AD accounts to another application which will compare its account expiration dates. The application cannot query AD directly.

Comment: I would personally create a dedicated service account and grant _that_ access to read the pertinent attributes - then use that account for the scheduled task. Computer accounts are ephemeral, subject to hardware lifecycles - don't tie tasks and permissions to their fleeting identity :)

Comment: thanks @MathiasR.Jessen you can post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, a process running under the system context **will assume the machine's domain identity for authenticated network calls** - and regular computer accounts have little reason to read the `accountExpires` of any account, since the only computers that should care about its value for operational purposes are Domain Controllers, so likely haven't been granted read access to it.

While it might be tempting to update the ACLs in the directory store to allow this random computer you're currently running your reporting tasks on to read the attribute value, I'd strongly caution against that - instead, **create a new dedicated user account in AD**, and use the credentials of that new account to query the directory in your script.

---

If you need to grant the new account *additional permissions*, make sure you follow [the AGDLP model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AGDLP):

- Create a new global or universal security group in AD, name it for the *task* being performed:

  - eg. `MT-AccountReporters`
- Create 1 or more domain-local security group(s) in AD, name each one for the permission(s) being delegated:

  - eg. `DLG-UserAccDetails-R`
- Grant each of the required permissions to the corresponding groups from the previous step
- Make the user account a member of `MT-AccountReports` group, then make the `MT-AccountReports` group a member of `DLG-UserAccDetails-R` (and any other delegation group created for this above)

This may sounds slightly overkill, but by separating delegation of permissions sets from the *tasks* the grantees need to perform, you'll now be able to implement other task delegations in the future without worrying about lifecycle maintenance of the ACLs